# Not getting back the column names after reading into an xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, ipython

Hello I have xlsx files and merged them into one dataframe by using pandas. It worked but instead of getting back the column names that I had in the xlsx file I got numbers as columns instead and the column titles became a row: Like this:

```
 Output:      1           2           3
            COLTITLE1    COLTITLE2     COLTITLE3
```

When they should be like this:

```
Output: COLTITLE1     COLTITLE2      COLTITLE3
```

The column titles are not column titles but rather they have become a row. How can I get back the rightful column names that I had within the xlsx file. Just for clarity all the column names are the same within both the xlsx files. Help would be appreciated heres my code below:

```
# import modules
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',100)
%matplotlib inline

# filenames
file_names = ["data/OrderReport.xlsx", "data/OrderReport2.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in file_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# concatenate them
atlantic_data = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You just need to get rid of the `index_col=None` and it will return the column name as usual:

```
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None) for x in excels]
```

If you add `index_col=None` pandas will treat your column name as 1 row of data rather than a column for the dataframe.

Comment: Well, I think another problem I spot from your script is that pd.concat may not be the right thing to do because the idea of pd.concat is not to merge your column but to merge your row.

So if you want to merge the columns from two excel, use pd.merge should generate what you want.

Comment: nope calling pd.merge(frames)  still doesnt work, would there be another way to read into multiple xlsx files?

Comment: if the xlsx file is not too big and you don't care much about speed (probably just 1-2 seconds slower), I will propose you to use pd.read_excel as it will directly return a DataFrame that optimize the setting of column and row.

pd.ExcelFile() is actually one of the components in pd.read_excel

Comment: Oh I am really sorry I haven't notice that the column names from both excels are the same. Please use pd.append when you want to concat the row of data from two excel files. You can find some examples here. [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html )

Comment: OK this is the next question I asked . Please take a look at this thanks @glibdud

Comment: OK in this question i re altered the code but got a different issue. Can you please assist me with this one @Andy Hayden

Comment: Hey Champ you helped me a couple of times ...can you take a look at this @jezrael

Comment: I know you are a pandas wiz can you check this out ! Much appreciated ! @piRSquared